# Jupyter Notebook exported HTML dark color

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I am using JupyterLab with light theme and when I exported my notebook as HTML I saw this:
[image: background color is dark and codes are in weird colors]

What I am expecting to see is something like this:
[image: background color is white]

any ideas of the setting ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. After a couple hours debugging I realized it had to do (for me at least) with the `jupyter-theme` library. I had a dark theme installed, and I think `nbconverter` uses whichever settings your `jupyter` is also using, so the dark settings were affecting the html conversion.

Solution was simply to restore defaults with: 
`$ jt -r`

If that doesn't work, then refer to this thread: https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/issues/86

Comment: I use Windows cmd and there is not any `jt -r`. Also in Notebook with `!jt -r`. Could you help me about it?

Answer (score 7):

from the command line run:

`jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html /path/to/example.ipynb --HTMLExporter.theme=dark`

adding `--execute` guarantees that plots are rendered before saving.

you can use Plotly dark theme to have plots black as well

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.templates.default = "plotly_dark"
```

[image]

Comment: Note: you can set `--HTMLExporter.theme=light` if you want to ensure everything is light themed

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Not only did the rendered html have a dark background, which made the x and y axis labels and ticks unreadable (they are black in color), but it also had weird alignment between blocks.

Although I do not know how to remedy it programmatically, I did find a work around.

1. Go to the official [jupyter lab online playground](https://jupyter.org/try).
2. Choose `Try Jupyter Lab`
3. Export `Lorentz.ipynb` (or any `.ipynb` file). You will find that this `Lorentz.html` is rendered correctly.
4. Replace the body and title of `Lorentz.html` with the body of your incorrectly-rendered html file `old_foo.html` (essentially, we are using `Lorentz.html`'s styling for `old_foo.html`'s body).
5. Rename `Lorentz.html` as `new_foo.html`. Open `new_foo.html` and you will find that it is correctly rendered.

If you run a diff between `new_foo.html` and `old_foo.html`, you will see that the difference is in one big chunk of styling code.

I am not sure whether this is a config error on my end or a bug in jupyter lab.

--

```
$ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.14.0
ipykernel        : 5.3.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.3
jupyter lab      : 2.1.3
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.0.6
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Vanila HTML exported from jupyter lab:

[image: Without styling change, wrongly rendered]

Replace styling with that from jupyter lab's online playground:

[image: With styling change, correctly rendered]

## Update

This hack **no longer** works in the following `jupyter` version:

```
╰─$ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.18.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
jupyter lab      : 2.2.8
nbconvert        : 6.0.6
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.0.7
traitlets        : 5.0.4
```

Comment: Try this: `plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = '#FFFFFF'`
If you need further styling, there is a lot more in `plt.rcParams` to tweak to your liking.